# Teradata - SQL SECURITY CREATOR

Tags: security, teradata

I am using the SQL SECURITY CREATOR stored proc hint to create a stored proc (logged in as DBC), but when I execute the proc as another user it appears that it does not have sufficient priveleges.

The idea (long term) is that the database names will be dynamic parameters passed into the proc - so tell me to just add the needed permissions.  This has to work at runtime.  I just hardcoded everything to demonstrate the crux of the problem.

Teradata 13.10 (VMWare test machine).

```
--Logged in as DBC
CREATE DATABASE dbAlpha FROM SYSDBA AS PERMANENT = 100;
CREATE DATABASE dbBravo FROM SYSDBA AS PERMANENT = 0;
CREATE DATABASE dbCharlie_Proc FROM SYSDBA AS PERMANENT = 200000;

GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE ON dbCharlie_Proc TO DBC;

Replace Procedure dbCharlie_Proc.GiveSpace (
    )
SQL SECURITY CREATOR --The stored proc will run under the security context of the     user     that created it - DBC in this case
--When you specify SQL SECURITY CREATOR, Teradata Database verifies and applies the privileges of the user who created the procedure.
BEGIN 
    DECLARE strSQL VARCHAR(8000);
    SET strSQL = 'CREATE DATABASE dbDelta_temp from SYSDBA as PERMANENT = 5';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSQL;
    SET strSQL = 'Give dbDelta_temp to dbBravo';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSQL;
    SET strSQL = 'drop database dbDelta_temp';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSQL;
End;

CALL dbCharlie_Proc.GiveSpace();
```

Gives me this error:

GIVESPACE:The user does not have DROP DATABASE access to database dbDelta_temp. (3524)

Comment: In the above example I just looked and saw my temp database owner is dbCharlie_proc, not DBC as I would have expected:    SELECT DatabaseName, CreatorName FROM dbc.Databases WHERE DatabaseName = 'dbDelta_temp';

Comment: I added a step to the proc (right before the "GIVE")  
  `code`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSQL;
 SET strSQL = 'GRANT DROP Database on dbDelta_temp to ' || user;`code`
and it works as long as I am logged in as DBC.

Comment: If a create a new user (uZulu) and grant that user execute procedure rights on dbCharlie_proc, when I execute the proc I get the same error about not having DROP DATABASE access.  I check DBC.AllRightsV and uZulu has DD on dbDelta_temp

Comment: Tried on a 14.10 virtual server and it worked as expected (without the 'GRANT DD' in the proc).  Is this an error/setting in 13.10?

Comment: The 13.10 VM was a very early patch level, this has probably been fixed.